# Set programmatically selectableItemBackground on Button. Android. Kotlin

Tags: android, button, kotlin, background

I have this code and it isn't working.

```
val background = TypedValue()        
context!!.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, background, true)

button.setBackground(background.resourceId)
```

> Error: Type mismatch; Found: Int; Required: Drawable.

Comment: change setBackground to setBackgroundResource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `setBackgroundResource(int id)`. Because `setBackground(Drawable d)` accepts a `Drawable` object.

```
val background = TypedValue()        
context!!.theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, background, true)
button.setBackgroundResource(background.resourceId)
```

Comment: Lol, thanks, It's work for me, but few minutes ago I try to use it, but I have this problem. It's like AndroidStudio have bugs?!